# Highchart, bar chart with multiple series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I display a bar chart with multiple series:

http://jsfiddle.net/qyd6w5tx/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts(


    {
        "chart": {
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial, sans-serif"
            },
                "alignTicks": false,
                "marginRight": 20,
                "height": 334
        },
            "tooltip": {
            "pointFormat": "<span style=\"color:{series.color}\">●</span> <span style=\"{series.options.style.pct}\">({point.percentage:,.2f}%)</span> <b style=\"{series.options.style.abs}\">{point.value:,.2f}</b><br/>"
        },
            "xAxis": {
            "type": "category",
                "reversed": false,
                "labels": {}
        },
            "yAxis": [{
            "title": {
                "text": null
            },
                "index": 0
        }, {
            "title": {
                "text": null
            },
                "labels": {
                "format": "{value}%"
            },
                "index": 1,
                "min": -0.39,
                "max": 9.99
        }, {
            "title": {
                "text": null
            },
                "labels": {
                "format": "{value}%"
            },
                "opposite": true,
                "index": 2
        }],
            "legend": {
            "borderWidth": 0,
                "enabled": false
        },
            "plotOptions": {
            "bar": {
                "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": true,
                        "style": {
                        "textShadow": "none"
                    },
                        "allowOverlap": true
                },
                    "minPointLength": 2
            },

        },
            "credits": {
            "enabled": false
        },
            "series": [{
            "name": "Group A",
                "type": "bar",
                "format": "pct",
                "top_value": "",
                "min_percent": "",
                "style": {
                "abs": "display: none"
            },
                "data": [{
                "name": "Test 01",
                    "value": 0.8,
                    "percentage": 0.8,
                    "y": 0.8
            }, {
                "name": "Test 02",
                    "value": 2,
                    "percentage": 2,
                    "y": 2
            }, {
                "name": "Test 03",
                    "value": -0.5,
                    "percentage": -0.5,
                    "y": -0.5
            }, {
                "name": "Test 04",
                    "value": 2.33,
                    "percentage": 2.33,
                    "y": 2.33
            }],
                "yAxis": 1
        }, {
            "name": "Group B",
                "type": "bar",
                "format": "pct",
                "top_value": "",
                "min_percent": "",
                "style": {
                "abs": "display: none"
            },
                "data": [{
                "name": "Test 05",
                    "value": 9,
                    "percentage": 9,
                    "y": 9
            }, {
                "name": "Test 06",
                    "value": 9,
                    "percentage": 9,
                    "y": 9
            }, {
                "name": "Test 07",
                    "value": 3,
                    "percentage": 3,
                    "y": 3
            }],
                "yAxis": 1
        }],
            "title": {
            "text": "Test"
        }
    }




    );
});
```

In this example I would like to display one after the other:

- Test 01
- Test 02
- Test 03
- Test 04
- Test 05
- Test 06
- Test 07

And then have the Group A in blue and the Group B in red, and display a legend under the chart with:
 - Group A (in blue)
 - Group B (in red)

I am bit confused with how to make this with highchart...

**Edit:**

Thanks to Rotan075 to understand my problem and to find a solution. http://jsfiddle.net/hw5s4ahm/

Actually I didn't specify that need to keep the same data structure for the series:

```
         "series": [{
            "name": "Group A",
                "type": "bar",
                "format": "pct",
                "top_value": "",
                "min_percent": "",
                "style": {
                "abs": "display: none"
            },
                "data": [{
                "name": "Test 01",
                    "value": 0.8,
                    "percentage": 0.8,
                    "y": 0.8
            }, {
                "name": "Test 02",
                    "value": 2,
                    "percentage": 2,
                    "y": 2
            }, {
                "name": "Test 03",
                    "value": -0.5,
                    "percentage": -0.5,
                    "y": -0.5
            }, {
                "name": "Test 04",
                    "value": 2.33,
                    "percentage": 2.33,
                    "y": 2.33
            }],
                "yAxis": 1
        }, {
            "name": "Group B",
                "type": "bar",
                "format": "pct",
                "top_value": "",
                "min_percent": "",
                "style": {
                "abs": "display: none"
            },
                "data": [{
                "name": "Test 05",
                    "value": 9,
                    "percentage": 9,
                    "y": 9
            }, {
                "name": "Test 06",
                    "value": 9,
                    "percentage": 9,
                    "y": 9
            }, {
                "name": "Test 07",
                    "value": 3,
                    "percentage": 3,
                    "y": 3
            }],
                "yAxis": 1
        }]
```

The rest can change, but this data is generated by a third part level and has to stay generic. I thought it would be just a question of settings but it seem to be much more complicated.

Comment: You seem to have most of it sorted out - can you be more specific about what isn't working the way you want it to?

Comment: "but it seem to be much more complicated" I am not understanding what is complicated? Can you elaborate? This should be pretty simple, unless there is something you haven't explained

Comment: I want the same output as Rotan075 demonstrate it but I need to keep the same data structure as provided in object series. So the main idea is to combine to bar chart in only one chart, in order to have the same scaling factor.

Comment: But that's the default behavior. This is why I am confused - what is not working for you?

Comment: With my data structure of the series, I want to have the same result as Rotan075. But in order to make the chart Rotan075 changed the data structure of my series.

Comment: Ok. But you aren't saying what is NOT working. Again, you are describing the default behavior of a highcharts grouped bar chart. Does my answer below do what you need? If not, what is not right? Be specific.

Comment: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/qyd6w5tx/2/ . We don't see Test 01, Test 02, Test 03. They have been combined to Test 04, Test 05, Test 06, Test 07.

Comment: That issue is addressed in the answer I added below, earlier. Specify categories on the x axis, and set a min and max value to always show all categories. This is the fiddle I posted as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/58/

Comment: I found a way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/qyd6w5tx/3/

Comment: Why you need your data strcture? What is reason of that? Now all works as you expected or Im wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For what I understood out of your code is that you have data for Group A and group B right? What you have to do is make two data list with each of the same length. If there is no data for the specific group you have to add a `null` value to it. Otherwise Highcharts combines the group A and group B for every Test x.

What you need is [this code (live on JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/hw5s4ahm/):

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts(
    {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            inverted: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter:function() {                                                  
                        if(this.y > 0){
                            return this.y;
                            return this.point.y;   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: -1,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: '   ',
                margin:40
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5','Test6','Test7']


        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            align:'middle',
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1,
            y:10,
            x:350
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'GroupA',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: [{y:null},{y:null}, {y:null}, {y:null}, {y:2.9}, {y:0.5}, {y:1.5}]
        },{
            name: 'GroupB',
            color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
            data: [{y:6.5}, {y:3.9}, {y:8.5}, {y:6.6},{y:null},{y:null},{y:null}]            
        }],
            title: {
            text: "Test"
        }
    }

    );
});
```

P.S. For aligning the Legend on the bottom of your graph I did that in a quite hackish way. I use as title text just blank space and place the legend above it. You can modify it in whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly how I want it to look like. The only problem is that I need the data structure for the series to stay the same as in my example. I thought it would have been possible to just play on the setting to get what I want but apparently it seem more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you are asking for should be handled by the default behavior of highcharts.

-You can specify the color for each series within the series options:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Group A',
  color: 'rgba(0,156,255,0.9)',
  data: [...]
},{
  name: 'Group B',
  color: 'rgba(204,0,0,0.9)',
  data: randomData(7)
}]
```

-You can set your x axis labels via the categories option:

```
xAxis: { 
  categories: ['Test 01','Test 02','Test 03','Test 04','Test 05','Test 06','Test 07']
}
```

-The chart will group them by default

-The legend will be aligned below the chart by default (no hacks required)

Example in action:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/57/

Updated example using your data:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/58/

Adds a min and max value to the x axis to always show each category